# Bracha Acharona after Hesech HaDaas

Tags: halacha, blessing, bentching

1. When eating a bread meal one makes the decision to end the meal, clears the table but then decides to continue eating. Question: Does this constitute Hesech HaDaas?
2. And if so, when saying a *bracha rishona* on this assumedly *new meal*, does it require a separate *bracha acharona*, or would it be covered by the *Birkas HaMazon* of the *previous meal*?

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Kitzur_Shulchan_Aruch.42.23?with=all&lang=bi

Comment: Thank you. It shall be a lesson for the future.

Comment: Berachot 42a; Shulchan Aruch O.C. 179.

Comment: Thank you Alex for these sources. The bracha rishona was shehakol on crackers which were not part of the bread meal. So it seems that everything settled appropriately.

Comment: See Arve Psachim, Baal Hamaor and Rif

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Yohanan and thanks for this first question. Can I recommend you take the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a sense of how the site works?  Great to have you learn with us!